# Alloy Editor : upload multiple images on my server from content

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, editor

Is it possible to upload the multiple images from pasted content of google drive document or local documents i.e articles ?

After pasting the content from document, i want to upload all images on my server
Currently, when i drop/select image (single) in editor area locally then using "imageAdd" event i can upload the image to my server, but same thing when i do by selecting the image (having google image url) from document that time its not working.

want to implement : all images which i have copied in editor which are hosted in different server, need to upload on my server

Answer (score 0):

You need a plugin that detects whenever content is copied into the editor, then find out any external image and then imports them into your server.

This is an example of such plugin https://www.pluginsforckeditor.com/imagesfromserver/ although you can write your own.